# Why didn't Two use the nanites before?

Tags: dark-matter

In the episode *Built, not born* Two

> injects Dr. Irena Shaw with her nanites to cure or at least delay her tumor.

Why didn't she do that the first time she was there? AFAIK she knew about the nanites and their abilities before her escape.

Was it

> because she now had the improved nanites

?